# Storing currencies with Coldfusion Orm

Tags: orm, coldfusion, cfml

I need to create a property in a CF Orm entity that stores currencies (dollars and cents).  For example: 100.99 or 1.30 etc.  I have traditionally used decimal to store currencies as you can foce the number of decimal points, but there is no ORM property type for decimal, only float.  I tried setting scale=2, but (for example) 1.30 was being stored as 1.3, or 5.00 is stored as 5.

Can anyone suggest the optimal way to work with currencies (having 2 decimal places) using CF ORM?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bob Silverberg has a good blog article on ColdFusion ORM data types "[CF9 ORM - Experimenting with type vs ormtype](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2009/9/15/CF9-ORM--Experimenting-with-type-vs-ormtype)".

Personally I prefer to store currencies as integers of their base unit e.g. cents as in 130 for $1.30 and then handle the decimal place at presentation. It also helps with possible rounding errors when dealing with computation of float values.

Comment: What a great idea. I've always stored file sizes in bytes rather than KB or MB. Never thought of taking the same approach with currency.

Answer (score 2):

Well there's a `big_decimal` `ormtype` according to the docs. And also don't forget that there's the `sqltype` property as well as the `ormtype` one. See docs: "[Map the properties](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Map+the+properties)". `sqltype` (and `scale` and `precision`) will let you set the DB column appropriately.

That said, this will mean that there's a disconnect between CF (any amount of decimal places) and the DB (which you'll be able to force to 2DP), which is a bit crap. I dunno if here's a way to automate the truncation... you might have to create a `setter()` method to deal with it.